# how should I Change app language from json in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a JSON file like this, how should I change the language using this JSON? Label key is english name, and Label value is translated value.

```
[
    {
        "language_name": "French",
        "language_short_code": "FR",
        "label_key": "Patient Name",
        "label_value": null,
        "language_display_order": 0,
        "language_is_default": 0
    },
    {
        "language_name": "French",
        "language_short_code": "FR",
        "label_key": "Doctor Id",
        "label_value": null,
        "language_display_order": 0,
        "language_is_default": 0
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has maps, which are basically JSON objects. They are written with the curly braces and consist of a key value pair. In your case you have a list of maps, with String keys and dynamic values.